# facebook meta tags generate ascii strings on Facebook post

Tags: php, facebook, encoding, smarty

I am using smarty for generating template. In particular, I generate Facebook meta tags

```
<meta property="title" content="{$title|escape}" />
```

The problem is the following, when I put links on a Facebook post, it generate an image and a text (that suppose taken from the meta tags values ?). Suppose I have several blog page which have the exact same format, when I refer to each of them by copy pasting their url on a Facebook post, the generated text is well formatted, except for some specific one, that 
is "ascii charactered" : "Baron sanglant : l'enquête" becomes "Baron+sanglant%3A+l%27enqu%C3%AAte". I tried to put `<meta property="title" content="{$title}" />` but it does not work. The weirdest, is that all the other blog posts (with the same special characters) behaves well. Could someone help ?

Answer (score -1):

This is not for Facebook usage, this is only a meta title. 
You should try to use:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="some site name" />
<meta property="og:description" content="some description" />
<meta content="some content" property="dc:title" />
<link rel="image_src" href="" />
```

and look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph